# Handle enter key press event inside jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Is there a way how to handle event on pressing enter key in jquery autocomplete function? If I click on item of dropdown result I go to following url

```
window.location.href = '/user?userId=' + ui.item.userId;
```

And it works fine in select section of function. But what if i need to change my url when I typed some letters and dropdown result list is shown but I don't click on one of items, instead i just press enter key, how can i handle it?

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/search/users",
            data: {
                query: request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var transformed = $.map(data, function(el) {
                    return {
                        name: el.name,
                        email: el.email
                    };
                });
                response(transformed);
            },
            error: function() {
                response([]);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        window.location.href = '/user?userId=' + ui.item.userId;
    }
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var $a = $("<a></a>").append(item.name);
    highlightText(this.term, $a);
    return $("<li></li>").append($a).appendTo(ul);
};
```

I tried with this, but I wonder if there is a better solution

```
$('#search').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && $(this).val()) {
        window.location.href = '/users/list?name=' + $(this).val();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the keypress idea. If you want an alternate solution I would suggest using a `form` tag:

```
<form action="/users/list" method="get">
    <input id="search" name="name">
</form>
```

The form will submit upon hitting enter provided the autocomplete menu is not *active*.